# How to get dataflow to prioritize CPU to I/O bound steps?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Google cloud dataflow pipeline (uses Apache Beam) which does some processing and exports to Elasticsearch. I'm finding that regardless of how many workers I throw at it, it dedicates resources to the processing and will tend to dedicate none to inserting completed windows into ES. The end result is that you have a bunch of documents to insert into ES at the tail end of the pipeline. This results in an overall less efficient pipeline, as you can't scale that last step beyond the insertion speed of ES, and they could have been inserted while the rest of the pipeline was processing.

I've tried both a streaming and batch pipeline, as well as various worker amounts. For a batch pipeline, this is just the normal behavior, as it loads up documents to insert into ES and then *finally* decides to insert them once all other processing is done.

For streaming, it behaves a little better - I can see that on occasion it gets to that step and starts inserting into ES, but eventually it stops doing this and spends all its time on the fetching/processing step until there's nothing left, then goes back to inserting into ES, which is always the same speed regardless of workers (tweaking the batch size and other things helps, but that is not the point of this question). I'm guessing if I used a very large number of workers things would continuously stream but that would be very wasteful and with the python SDK there's no automatic scaling so trying to find the magic number is a large time sink. There's very much diminishing returns when adding workers.

Pipeline usage:

```py
def get_group_key_and_value_for_es_inserts(item):
   returns a tuple of (partition, item) where partition is simply a number between [0, 7)
```

Pipeline flow:

```py
- Fetch from datasource (i.e. pubsub or datastore query)
- Window by time (every 5 seconds) and divide into 13 groups using GroupByKey (also tried 29 groups)
- Fetch from service using batch calls to augment data
- Process
- Insert into ES (7 groups)
- Insert failures into BigQuery

...
        | "Timestamp" >> beam.Map(lambda e: TimestampedValue(e, time.time()))
        | "Window" >> beam.WindowInto(
            FixedWindows(window_size_seconds),
            trigger=Repeatedly(AfterWatermark()),
            accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)
...
        | "Prep for ES insert grouping" >> beam.Map(get_group_key_and_value_for_es_inserts)
        | "Group for ES insert" >> beam.GroupByKey()
        | "Insert into Elasticsearch" >> beam.ParDo(InsertIntoEs())
...
```

DoFn:

```py
class InsertIntoEs(beam.DoFn):

    def build_failure(self, doc):
        ... code ...

    def process(self, (_, docs)):
        if len(docs) == 0:
            return []
        logging.info("Inserting %s docs into ES" % len(docs))
        actions = [{
            '_op_type': 'index',
            '_index': doc.index,
            '_id': doc.es_id,
            '_source': doc
        } for doc in docs]
        insert_failures = []
        for ok, result in helpers.streaming_bulk(
                es_client, actions, chunk_size=batch_size, max_retries=max_retries,
                raise_on_error=False, raise_on_exception=False):
            if not ok:
                action, doc = result.popitem()
                insert_failures.append(self.build_failure(doc))
        if len(insert_failures) > 0:
            logging.warn("Got %s insert failures" % len(insert_failures))
        return insert_failures
```

The inserts into ES batch calls take *seconds* so there's not a lot of CPU overhead to that step. If it could start inserting as soon as documents were ready, the pipeline would finish sooner.

Also I more or less have this problem in other steps - it tends to send all CPU resources to whatever the first step that isn't 100% completed is, when in reality it would be more efficient if it just built windows and focused on seeing windows to completion with spare CPU going to the earlier steps, since there are a few I/O bottlenecks in the pipeline that would benefit from that parallelism.

Edit: Finding that throwing 2x more workers at the streaming pipeline doesn't improve anything. It seems to simply be wasting those extra resources.

Comment: If the task is I/O heavy with only minor CPU usage, how would giving it priority on the CPU(s) help?

Comment: Because it's not being executed at all when it could be executed for minimal impact on the upstream processing.

Answer (score 1):

Dataflow fuses steps of your pipeline and and creates fused steps. 'GroupByKey' step acts as a fusion boundary. So in your pipeline, everything up to "Prep for ES insert grouping" and writing into shuffle (GroupByKey) will be one step and reading from shuffle and executing "Insert into Elasticsearch" will be a second step.

Also, Dataflow processes data element by element, data get pushed from one step to to the other based on the triggering policy you have defined. So in you case, it's expected behavior for Dataflow to prepare data for a given window, and trigger write (fused) step when that window is ready to be finished (after watermark reaches window end boundary). Adding more workers will not change this behavior (but may make overall execution faster since it can be parallelized more).

Hope this clarifies the execution characteristics you are observing.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered one solution to get something resembling this behavior is to trigger on processing time. By windowing in the following way, I get a continuous stream of inserts, although it overall seems to be less efficient:

Example:

```py
        beam.WindowInto(
            FixedWindows(window_size_seconds),
            trigger=Repeatedly(
                AfterAny(
                    AfterProcessingTime(window_size_seconds),
                    AfterCount(window_size_count),
                )),
            accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)
```

The downside is that I found this can severely throttle the pipeline if the parameters (window size, count) are too small for the number of workers.

Not really seeing a best solution here unfortunately.